# Limit of integral of measurable function

Tags: integration, limits, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space and f a non negative measurable function. Let $E=\{x \in E: f(x) < 1\}$. Calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E e^{-f^n} d\mu.$$

I'm having some trouble in exercises on integrability. I know that because $f < 1$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-f^n} = e^0 = 1.$$ What can I do else?

Comment: What have you tried? Or is this all what you could deduce about the problem?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Can I exchange limit with integral? This was all I could deduce. I think about a lot of things but I don't know a lot about measure theory.

Comment: Hint: Monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Thanks @Klaus..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sequence $g_n = e^{-f^n}$. Note that $(g_n\chi_E)_{n\geq 1}$ is an increasing sequence of non-negative measurable functions, so you can use the Monotone convergence theorem. The limit of the integrals is $\mu(E)$.